# ImageMagick: delete input files when appending?

Tags: imagemagick

When I try

```
magick mogrify +append 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg
```

I get an error saying: "mogrify: unable to open 3.jpg". Is there a way to automatically delete the two input files?

Comment: You cannot use mogrify to do that. Just use magick.  `magick 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg +append result.jpg` Mogrify takes one input and  makes one output for every input provided. It does not work with multiple inputs and a single output.

Comment: When I do that the input files remain. I want only result.jpg to remain

Comment: Input files are always deleted from memory using magick when you do +append.  What is your Imagemagick version and platform? How many input images do you have -- Post your exact command line.

Comment: Do you mean deleted from your hard drive or from memory or output? Define deleted in your situation?  Deleted where?

Comment: Imagemagick will never delete your files from hard drive. That is up to you to do with your OS.

Answer (score 1):

Just collating the comments together for clarity...

You can append 3 images side-by-side, and remove the input images if the command succeeds like this:

```
magick 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg +append result.jpg && rm [123].jpg
```

[image]

---

By the way, `+append` is quite long in the tooth and there is a more recent, more useful operator called `+/-smush` which works exactly the same as `+/-append` but allows you to create a gap with the `+smush` version and an overlap with the `-smush` version:

```
magick 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg -background black +smush 10 result.jpg && rm [123].jpg
```

[image]